# SQL Group BY when criteria is met leave as is if not

Tags: sql

apologies if this has been asked before. Similar questions have been raised. These were noted , reviewed and applied but does not deliver my desired result. I am sure to most this is very trivial. I would appreciate guidance into the right direction. Basically what I want to achieve is group set of items from a db if criteria has been satisfied and leave as is the items i.e. not group if it does not meet.

```
Example 
=========
id   chk  chk2  chk3   
1    2     3     3    
2    2     3     3    
3    2     3     3       
4    3     2     2        
5    3     1     1       
6    5     1     1
```

Desired Output

```
id   chk  chk2 chk3   
1     2    3    3       
4     3    2    2      
5     3    1    1      
6     5    1    1
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve is group anything by **chk** if qty is >2 and leave as is if not.

How this can be achieved?

What I did is as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM db_name 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN COUNT(*)>2 THEN chk,chk2,chk3 ELSE NULL END
```

Comment: Nothing in your data is called `qyt` so the question is unclear.

Comment: qty means quantity if chk>2

Comment: If you simply group by chk, chk2, chk3 with a MIN(id) then you'll also get those expected results.  So you might want to modify that sample data & expected result a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using correlated subquery

```
   select * from tablename a
     where id in (select min(id) from tablename b where a.chk=b.chk)
```

Comment: hi guys I am still struggling to achieve the desired result. The intent of this exercise is to group all those items with the same chk having count more than 2 and leave the rest as-is when this condition is not met. Can you assist?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select min(id), chk, chk2, chk3
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by chk, chk2, chk3) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
group by (case when cnt > 2 then null else id end),
         chk, chk2, chk3;
```

Or just window functions:

```
select id, chk, chk2, chk3
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by chk, chk2, chk3) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by chk, chk2, chk3 order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where cnt <= 2 or seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

With UNION:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) ID, chk, chk2, chk3 
FROM db_name
where chk > 2
GROUP BY chk, chk2, chk3  
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, chk, chk2, chk3 
FROM db_name 
where chk <= 2
```

Comment: For the sample data you posted it works. If there is something else you should explain.